# Return one record from multiple records

Tags: sql

I have two tables, which when combined will give me the following information

```
JobID     Task ID     Task Status
1           1            1
1           2            3
1           3            1
1           4            1
1           5            3
2           1            1
2           3            1 
2           5            1
```

What I would like to display is one line for each job ID and the status based on the following 

When all task statues are 1 then the job status is "Started" 
If one task status is set to 3 then the job status is "Issued" 
so the following will be true for the table above

```
Job ID   Job Status
 1        Issued
 2        Started
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer uses full conditional aggregation, under the assumption that down the road your data might change.

```
SELECT
    [Job ID],
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN [Task Status] = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
         THEN 'Issued'
         WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN [Task Status] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*)
         THEN 'Started'
         ELSE 'Other' END AS [Job Status]
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    [Job ID];
```

For more concise versions of this query assuming the only statuses are 1 and 3, see the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Use `GROUP BY` to combine items with identical job IDs. Use `MIN(TaskStatus)` and `MAX(TaskStatus)` to see if all items are the same or not:

```
SELECT
    JobId
,   CASE
        WHEN MIN(TaskStatus) = 1 AND MAX(TaskStatus) = 1 THEN 'Started'
        WHEN MAX(TaskStatus) = 3 THEN 'Issued'
        ELSE NULL
    END AS JobStatus
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY JobId
```

Comment: This assume there are only two `TaskStatus = {1,3}`. Just be carefull if that isnt the case

Comment: Maybe `MIN(TaskStatus) = 1 AND` is not needed if TaskStatus cannot be less than 1

Comment: @Don Good chances are that you're right. I am not sure what other data may be in that table, so I decided to do it defensively.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have it working now. There are other conditions when the Job Status may be different but that is related to a different table entirely. I have it all working perfectly now, that was the last piece of the puzzle

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `MAX` function to determine if there is a 3 in the list.

```
SELECT
    JobID,
    CASE
        WHEN MAX(TaskStatus) = 1 THEN 'Started',
        WHEN MAX(TaskStatus) = 3 THEN 'Issued'
        ELSE 'No Status'
    END AS 'JobStatus'
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    JobID
```